# Create infinite loop in one function that is cancelled in another

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to write a small little GUI that can start an audio recording with one button and end the recording with another.
I have written a recorder class that essentially does the following

```py
class RecordAudio:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rec = True
    def start_recording(self):
        while self.rec:
            record()
    def end_recording(self):
        self.rec = False
```

What is the mechanism, that I can use such that the recording continues on, while still enabling me to stop the recording using the function end_recording()? Or more precisely, what is the best practice for this problem?
I have tried to make the start_recording function async, but this doesn't work, as start_recording never finishes its computation.
Basically I would like to be able to do something like

```py
import asyncio

rec = True

async def start_loop():
    global rec
    while rec:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Slept another second")
    print("Stopped loop")

def stop_loop():
    global rec
    rec = False
    print("Stopping loop")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(start_loop())
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    stop_loop()
```

But where start_loop does not sleep but is continuously performing some endless task.

Comment: What exactly does "record()"? Does it return from time to time and must be called again or doesn't it return?

Comment: record() does not return, it continuously records using the pyaudio library. The class is reduced to the base functionality, if it would help I could add some detail to the question.

Comment: Are you using some kind of GUI framework or how do you intend to show this to the user?

Comment: Right now I am just learning with tkinter, the idea would be to have a list of recordings and two buttons, start and end recording.

Comment: Threading seems to me a better approach here than asynchronous coroutines. I haven't found a "record" function in the "pyaudio" docs. pyaudio recording works with a loop  or a callback. In both cases a variable like "rec" can be checked if recording should stop.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I was using the blocking mode (I think) and I should have used the callback mode!

Answer (score 0):

As said by Michael in the comments, I was using the wrong mode. The documentation gives to modes to operate either a blocking mode or a callback mode. In the callback mode it is possible to start recording in one function, while another function can change the state such that the recording stops.